# Alterar cor de Texto em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Caros;

Tenho uma página html que trás três informações do Banco de Dados Mysql (
HIGH, Medium e Low). Queria que apenas a palavra
HIGH fosse em vermelho, a Medium em Laranja e Low em Azul. Tentei fazer via PHP com Swicth Case, porem sem sucesso. Como não conheço nada de Jquery, queria ter uma ideia e ou ajuda de vocês para fazer. Procurei bastante na Internet, porem sem sucesso. Exemplo da parte em HTML:

```
<td><font size='1'><div id=add9 align=middle style='color: XXX ' > HIGH<td>
```

Não sei se existe algum Pluguin em Jquery, que faz a varredura da div, localiza o texto e mediante ao texto ele muda a cor do mesmo.

Exemplo da minha tabela :

```
 $row['subject']."</td><td>"."<font size='1'>"."<div id='div_result' align='middle'>".
   $row['score']."</div>"."<td><a href=delete.php?id=".
```

Trecho html:

```
<table class="table table-bordred table-striped" >

               <thead>

               <th><input type="checkbox" id="idALL" name="nameALL" onClick="CheckAll()" /></th>
               <th>Qtde</th>
               <th>Data</th>
               <th>IP</th>
                <th>Hostname</th>
                 <th>Sender</th>
                 <th>Subject</th>
                 <th>Score</th>
```

Grato em quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Com jQuery: `if ($("#add9").html() == "HIGH") { $("#add9").css("color", "red") }`. Mas lembre-se, se houver mais de uma `div` com o texto "HIGH", use `class` ao invés de `id` no jQuery.

Comment: As informações vem através de um While, então a mesma div (add9) é usado tanto para Hight, Medium e Low), desta forma, trabalho apenas nos Ifs'?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode percorrer todas as células da tabela, comparar o texto e adicionar uma classe, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tbody tr td").each(function(){
       if($(this).text() == "LOW")
        $(this).addClass('low');
       else if ($(this).text() == "MEDIUM")
        $(this).addClass('medium');
       else if ($(this).text() == "HIGH")
        $(this).addClass('high');
    });
});
```

```css
.low{
  color:blue;
}
.medium{
  color:yellow;
}
.high{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tboby>
  <tr>
    <td>LOW</td>
    <td>HIGH</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>MEDIUM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LOW</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIGH</td>
    <td>HIGH</td>
  </tr>
</tboby>
</table>
```

Alternativa para código jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tbody tr td").each(function(){
       var text = $(this).text();
       if(text == "LOW" || text == "MEDIUM" || text == "HIGH")
          $(this).addClass(text.toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19yc1kdL/1/)**

Comment: o conteúdo das tabelas é construído por um While, na minha pergunta acima editei para exemplificar, saberiam me dizer que neste caso é necessário fazer algum "macete"? Pois segui todos os passos que colocaram aqui e nada muda. Não é alterado nenhuma cor

Answer (score 0):

Defina uma classe na sua "div" de modo que fique parecida como esta:

```
<div class="div_result" id="add9" align="middle">HIGH</div>
```

Função para varrer todas as divs da classe e alterar a cor do texto:

```
function AlteraStyleDasDivs() {
  $(".div_result").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "HIGH")
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    else
    if ($(this).text() == "Medium")
      $(this).css("color", "orange");
    else
    if ($(this).text() == "Low")
      $(this).css("color", "blue");
  });
}
```

Por fim, chame a função após o carregamento da sua página:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  AlteraStyleDasDivs();
});
```

Comment: Caros; o conteúdo das tabelas é construído por um While, na minha pergunta acima editei para exemplificar, saberiam me dizer que neste caso é necessário fazer algum "macete"? Pois segui todos os passos que colocaram aqui e nada muda. Não é alterado nenhuma cor.

Comment: O While é executado ao carregar a página ou é retorno Ajax? Se for o primeiro caso, o exemplo que citei acima deve funcionar corretamente. Se for o segundo, após a finalização do Ajax, você deve chamar a função `AlteraStyleDasDivs();`.

Comment: No trecho da amostra do código "**Exemplo da minha tabela**" que você postou, há um pequeno erro. Corrija para: ..`<div class='div_result'`..

Comment: O while é executado ao carregar a pagina, ele vai ate o banco de dados e trás as informações via $row e com o echo exibe na página. Eu ajustei lá e nada, não altera nenhuma cor. Usei o exemplo do amigo acima também e nada, como não conheço jquery e nem java script, to apanhando pra algo tão simples.

Comment: Consegue postar todo o código da página? Se não for muito grande lógico...